# Java implementation of multivariate gradient descent

Tags: java, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I'm trying to implement the multivariate gradient descent algorithm in Java (from AI coursera course), and I cannot figure where is the fault located in my code.

This is the output of the below program:

```
Before train: parameters := [0.0, 0.0, 0.0] -> cost function := 2.5021875E9
After first iteration: parameters := [378.5833333333333, 2.214166666666667, 50043.75000000001] -> cost function := 5.404438291015627E9
```

As you can see, after first iteration, the values are way off. What am I doing wrong?

This is the algorithm I'm trying to implement:

[image]

And the code:

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class GradientDescent {

        private double[][] trainingData;
        private double[]   means;
        private double[]   scale;

        private double[]   parameters;
        private double     learningRate;

        GradientDescent() {
            this.learningRate = 0D;
        }

        public double predict(double[] inp){
            double[] features = new double[inp.length + 1];
            features[0] = 1;
            for(int i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
                features[i+1] = inp[i];
            }

            double prediction = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
                prediction = parameters[i] * features[i];
            }

            return prediction;
        }

        public void train(){
            double[] tempParameters = new double[parameters.length];
            for(int i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
                tempParameters[i] = parameters[i] - learningRate * partialDerivative(i);
                //System.out.println(tempParameters[i] + " = " + parameters[i] + " - " + learningRate + " * " + partialDerivative(i));
            }

            System.out.println("Before train: parameters := " + Arrays.toString(parameters) + " -> cost function := " + costFunction());
            parameters = tempParameters;
            System.out.println("After first iteration: parameters := " + Arrays.toString(parameters) + " -> cost function := " + costFunction());
        }

        private double partialDerivative(int index) {
            double sum = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < trainingData.length; i++) {
                double[] input = new double[trainingData[i].length - 1];
                int j = 0;
                for(; j < trainingData[i].length - 1; j++) {
                    input[j] = trainingData[i][j];
                }
                sum += ((predict(input) - trainingData[i][j]) * trainingData[i][index]);
            }

            return (1D/trainingData.length) * sum;
        }

        public double[][] getTrainingData() {
            return trainingData;
        }
        public void setTrainingData(double[][] data) {
            this.trainingData = data;
            this.means = new double[this.trainingData[0].length-1];
            this.scale = new double[this.trainingData[0].length-1];

            for(int j = 0; j < data[0].length-1; j++) {
                double min = data[0][j], max = data[0][j];
                double sum = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    if(data[i][j] < min) min = data[i][j];
                    if(data[i][j] > max) max = data[i][j];
                    sum += data[i][j];
                }
                scale[j] = max - min;
                means[j] = sum / data.length;
            }
        }   

        public double[] getParameters() {
            return parameters;
        }
        public void setParameters(double[] parameters) {
            this.parameters = parameters;
        }

        public double getLearningRate() {
            return learningRate;
        }
        public void setLearningRate(double learningRate) {
            this.learningRate = learningRate;
        }

        /**              1      m           i     i  2
        *   J(theta) = ----- * SUM( h     (x ) - y  )
        *               2*m    i=1   theta
        */  
        public double costFunction() {
            double sum = 0;

            for(int i = 0; i < trainingData.length; i++) {
                double[] input = new double[trainingData[i].length - 1];
                int j = 0;
                for(; j < trainingData[i].length - 1; j++) {
                    input[j] = trainingData[i][j];
                }
                sum += Math.pow(predict(input) - trainingData[i][j], 2);
            }

            double factor = 1D/(2*trainingData.length);
            return factor * sum;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("hypothesis: ");
            int i = 0;
            sb.append(parameters[i++] + " + ");
            for(; i < parameters.length-1; i++) {
                sb.append(parameters[i] + "*x" + i + " + ");
            }
            sb.append(parameters[i] + "*x" + i);

            sb.append("\n Feature scale: ");
            for(i = 0; i < scale.length-1; i++) {
                sb.append(scale[i] + " ");
            }
            sb.append(scale[i]);

            sb.append("\n Feature means: ");
            for(i = 0; i < means.length-1; i++) {
                sb.append(means[i] + " ");
            }
            sb.append(means[i]);

            sb.append("\n Cost fuction: " + costFunction());

            return sb.toString();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            final double[][] TDATA = {
                {200, 2, 20000},
                {300, 2, 41000},
                {400, 3, 51000},
                {500, 3, 61500},
                {800, 4, 41000},
                {900, 5, 141000}
            };

            GradientDescent gd = new GradientDescent();
            gd.setTrainingData(TDATA);
            gd.setParameters(new double[]{0D,0D,0D});
            gd.setLearningRate(0.00001);
            gd.train();
            //System.out.println(gd);
            //System.out.println("PREDICTION: " + gd.predict(new double[]{300, 2}));
        }
    }
```

---

EDIT:

I've updated the code to make it more readable, and tried to map it to the notation Douglas used. I think it's working better now, but there are still shady areas I don't fully understand.

It seems that if I have multiple parameters (like in the example below, number of rooms and area), the prediction is strongly related to the second parameter (in this case area), and it doesn't have much effect changing the first parameter (number of rooms).

Here is prediction for `{2, 200}`:

```
PREDICTION: 200000.00686158828
```

Here is prediction for `{5, 200}`:

```
PREDICTION: 200003.0068315415
```

As you can see there is barely any difference between the two values.

Are there still faults in my attempt to translate the math into code?

Here is the updated code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class GradientDescent {

    private double[][] trainingData;
    private double[]   means;
    private double[]   scale;

    private double[]   parameters;
    private double     learningRate;

    GradientDescent() {
        this.learningRate = 0D;
    }

    public double predict(double[] inp) {
        return predict(inp, this.parameters);
    }
    private double predict(double[] inp, double[] parameters){
        double[] features = concatenate(new double[]{1}, inp);

        double prediction = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < features.length; j++) {
            prediction += parameters[j] * features[j];
        }

        return prediction;
    }

    public void train(){
        readjustLearningRate();

        double costFunctionDelta = Math.abs(costFunction() - costFunction(iterateGradient()));

        while(costFunctionDelta > 0.0000000001) {
            System.out.println("Old cost function : " + costFunction());
            System.out.println("New cost function : " + costFunction(iterateGradient()));
            System.out.println("Delta: " + costFunctionDelta);

            parameters = iterateGradient();
            costFunctionDelta = Math.abs(costFunction() - costFunction(iterateGradient()));
            readjustLearningRate();
        }
    }

    private double[] iterateGradient() {
        double[] nextParameters = new double[parameters.length];
        // Calculate parameters for the next iteration
        for(int r = 0; r < parameters.length; r++) {
            nextParameters[r] = parameters[r] - learningRate * partialDerivative(r);
        }

        return nextParameters;
    }
    private double partialDerivative(int index) {
        double sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < trainingData.length; i++) {
            int indexOfResult = trainingData[i].length - 1;
            double[] input = Arrays.copyOfRange(trainingData[i], 0, indexOfResult);
            sum += ((predict(input) - trainingData[i][indexOfResult]) * trainingData[i][index]);
        }

        return sum/trainingData.length ;
    }
    private void readjustLearningRate() {

        while(costFunction(iterateGradient()) > costFunction()) {           
            // If the cost function of the new parameters is higher that the current cost function
            // it means the gradient is diverging and we have to adjust the learning rate
            // and recalculate new parameters
            System.out.print("Learning rate: " + learningRate + " is too big, readjusted to: ");
            learningRate = learningRate/2;
            System.out.println(learningRate);
        }
        // otherwise we are taking small enough steps, we have the right learning rate
    }

    public double[][] getTrainingData() {
        return trainingData;
    }
    public void setTrainingData(double[][] data) {
        this.trainingData = data;
        this.means = new double[this.trainingData[0].length-1];
        this.scale = new double[this.trainingData[0].length-1];

        for(int j = 0; j < data[0].length-1; j++) {
            double min = data[0][j], max = data[0][j];
            double sum = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if(data[i][j] < min) min = data[i][j];
                if(data[i][j] > max) max = data[i][j];
                sum += data[i][j];
            }
            scale[j] = max - min;
            means[j] = sum / data.length;
        }
    }   

    public double[] getParameters() {
        return parameters;
    }
    public void setParameters(double[] parameters) {
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }

    public double getLearningRate() {
        return learningRate;
    }
    public void setLearningRate(double learningRate) {
        this.learningRate = learningRate;
    }

    /**              1      m           i     i  2
    *   J(theta) = ----- * SUM( h     (x ) - y  )
    *               2*m    i=1   theta
    */  
    public double costFunction() {
        return costFunction(this.parameters);
    }
    private double costFunction(double[] parameters) {
        int m = trainingData.length;
        double sum = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            int indexOfResult = trainingData[i].length - 1;
            double[] input = Arrays.copyOfRange(trainingData[i], 0, indexOfResult);
            sum += Math.pow(predict(input, parameters) - trainingData[i][indexOfResult], 2);
        }

        double factor = 1D/(2*m);
        return factor * sum;
    }

    private double[] normalize(double[] input) {
        double[] normalized = new double[input.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            normalized[i] = (input[i] - means[i]) / scale[i];
        }

        return normalized;
    }

    private double[] concatenate(double[] a, double[] b) {
        int size = a.length + b.length;

        double[] concatArray = new double[size];
        int index = 0;

        for(double d : a) {
            concatArray[index++] = d;
        }
        for(double d : b) {
            concatArray[index++] = d;
        }

        return concatArray;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("hypothesis: ");
        int i = 0;
        sb.append(parameters[i++] + " + ");
        for(; i < parameters.length-1; i++) {
            sb.append(parameters[i] + "*x" + i + " + ");
        }
        sb.append(parameters[i] + "*x" + i);

        sb.append("\n Feature scale: ");
        for(i = 0; i < scale.length-1; i++) {
            sb.append(scale[i] + " ");
        }
        sb.append(scale[i]);

        sb.append("\n Feature means: ");
        for(i = 0; i < means.length-1; i++) {
            sb.append(means[i] + " ");
        }
        sb.append(means[i]);

        sb.append("\n Cost fuction: " + costFunction());

        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final double[][] TDATA = {
            //number of rooms, area, price
            {2, 200, 200000},
            {3, 300, 300000},
            {4, 400, 400000},
            {5, 500, 500000},
            {8, 800, 800000},
            {9, 900, 900000}
        };

        GradientDescent gd = new GradientDescent();
        gd.setTrainingData(TDATA);
        gd.setParameters(new double[]{0D, 0D, 0D});
        gd.setLearningRate(0.1);
        gd.train();
        System.out.println(gd);
        System.out.println("PREDICTION: " + gd.predict(new double[]{3, 600}));
    }
}
```

Comment: Which parts don't you fully understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have a reasonable start, but there were some issues in the translation of the math to code.  See the following math.

[image: The math]

There were a few steps I took to clarify the math and the algorithm's convergence mechanism.

1. To increase legibility, rather than use a parenthetic superscript to denote rows, a more standard comma delimited subscript was used in the notation.
2. An attempt was made to use a zero base for the summation control variables to match the Java/C index convention without introducing bugs into the math.  (Hopefully done correctly.)
3. Made the various substitutions implied by the course material.
4. Determined the mapping between variable names in the posted code and the mathematical representation.

After that, it became aparent that there is more awry than the missing plus sign in the summation loop.  The partial derivative seems to need rewriting or significant modification to match the course concepts.

Note that the inner loop of k=0->n to produces a dot product across all features and then is applied within the i=0->m-1 loop to account for each training case.

All of that must be contained within each iteration r.  The loop criteria for that outer loop should not be some maximum r value.  You will need some criteria that is met once convergence is sufficiently complete.

---

**Additional Notes in response to comments:**

It is difficult to spot incongruities as the code stands because of what Martin Fowler termed the Symantic Gap. In this case, it is between three things.

1. math representation
2. lecture terminology
3. algorithms in code

It is likely that refactoring the member variable and breaking the y vector from the x matrix (shown below) will facilitate spotting incongruities.

```
private int countMExamples;  
private int countNFeatures;  
private double[][] aX;  
private double[] aY;  
private double[] aMeans;  
private double[] aScales;  
private double[] aParamsTheta;  
private double learnRate;
```

Comment: Hi Douglas, I've updated my code but I'm not sure if I've got everything right as I still have open questions.

Comment: Also if I still have faults in my math, could you please point their exact location. Thanks!

Comment: Nice job on the LaTeX, Douglas Daseeco.

Comment: @DouglasDaseeco, sorry for the late reply. Yes I've fixed the problems. It was clear to me what I'm doing wrong after the refactor.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `+` when calculating your prediction. You should be summing the weight * input values with

`prediction += parameters[i] * features[i];`

as the activation function which produces the partial derivative you're using is h<sub>θ</sub> = Σ<sub>i</sub> x<sup>i</sup>θ<sup>i</sup>.

Also, it looks like you're going to need to reduce your learning rate to get the training function to converge.

--

I don't know the content of the course, so I'm not sure if you're expecting specific results, however I think the issue now lies in your training data.

Your training data provides no distinction as to how significantly either input impacts the result, as the both inputs increase proportionally with one another yielding a proportionally increased result. I would suggest providing a dataset with greater variation and less dependence between the two inputs.

If you're struggling with obtaining data to use you could try the [UCI housing data set.](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Housing) (Actually you'll have better luck with the the data provided below).

--

I've run your new code and with the following problems addressed it works well. Your update has introduced two key flaws, your dynamic learning rate and your training termination case.

A dynamic learning rate is a valid approach, however creating a function to appropriately reduce the learning rate can be difficult. Your current approach reduces the learning rate too quickly, causing it to dwindle to a  value that makes such negligible changes to your weights the algorithm prematurely stops. For the time being, keep a constant learning rate and manually tweak it.

For your training termination case, requiring such a small change in the cost function as your condition will cause the algorithm to over-train on your training data. The result will be that the algorithm will perform well on the training data, but poorly on anything new as it is predicting based on details unique to the training data.

I would advise greatly reducing the requirement, or better, implementing a train-validate loop. Each iteration you test your parameters on a distinct validation set, and terminate based on that performance.

Also, my above suggestion for input data was poor for a simple gradient descent algorithm. The housing data set is not linearly separable, and so a gradient descent algorithm (which optimizes the linear function h<sub>θ</sub>) will only make predictions generally close to the average.

Instead you should use data which is linearly separable, such as the [UCI Iris data set](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Iris). With the above two problems addressed your algorithm works accurately with this data.

Finally I agree with Douglas that you should consider rewriting your algorithm to be more clear. While the current implementation works, it will help your learning process if your code is concise and organized. You're using variable names that aren't descriptive, mixing procedural and OOP approaches, and haphazardly encapsulating methods.

Comment: I also agree with Douglas Daseeco that the algorithm clarity needs improvement. It was difficult to map the math in the course to the variable names as it is. Your excellent point is that the reduction of the learning rate is too fast and could possibly fall into chaos or diverge.